# wpf, BitmapDecoder issue

Tags: wpf, bitmap, icons

In a dialog window's code-behond, I select icon size based on my application's font size the following way:

```
double iconSize = 24;
if (Session.FontSize <= 16)
  iconSize = 48;
else if (Session.FontSize >= 28)
  iconSize = 72;

Uri uri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/MyApp;component/Resources/
                                               Status-dialog-information.ico");
BitmapDecoder decoder = BitmapDecoder.Create(uri, 
                                          BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation,
                                          BitmapCacheOption.Default);
BitmapSource bms = decoder.Frames.
                   Where(f => f.Width == iconSize).FirstOrDefault(); 
imageControl.Source = bms;
```

, where imageControl is, well, Image control. I use icons from Oxygen set (found in iconarchive.com)

Now, the above code works with some of the icons, with no problem.
But for some other icon files, such as the above, it works when I create my dialog window for the first time only. Second time I creat a dialog window BitmapDecoder.Create() method throws System.IO.FileFormatException - "The image format is unrecognized". Please suggest how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably difficult to answer, without more details. I just created static field to initialize once.